# Rational numbers and periodic decimal representation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove that a number is rational if and only if it has an eventually periodic decimal expansion. One part is simple; without loss of generality we consider $q=0.\overline{d_1\dots d_k},$ set $p=d_1\dots d_k$ so
$$q=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{p}{10^{kn}}=\frac{p}{10^k-1}\in\mathbb{Q}.$$
To prove the converse, I have been given the hint to apply the pigeonhole principle. Can someone give some suggestions (or just post the answer if you like; it's not homework) because I'm not too familiar or confident in using the pigeonhole principle, even though I feel like it might be some simple trick I don't see right now.

Thanks.

Comment: How about $$\frac1{2^a 5^b}?$$ Is it periodic & rational ?

Comment: You should probably say something like "eventually periodic". I think this is what @labbhattacharjee is referring to.

Answer (score 15):

To see that every rational has an eventually repeating decimal representation, suppose the rational is $\pm a/b$ with $a\geq 0$ and $b>1$ (we may exclude $b=1$ since then $a/b$ is integral and so has a decimal representation ending in a repeating string of zeroes already). Then just perform long division of $a$ by $b$. At each successive step in the long division, you either get a remainder of $0$ (and you are done, the decimal representation ends in a repeating string of zeroes), or you get a positive integral remainder which must lie in $\{1,\ldots,b-1\}$. There are at most $b-1$ possible distinct remainders, so by the $b^{\textrm{th}}$ successive step you must have a repeated remainder; the sequences of successive remainders must then repeat those previously encountered since they repeat, in order, producing the same sequence of generated digits in the quotient as desired.

Answer (score 4):

Let $q=\dfrac{a}{b}\in\mathbb Q$ be given. Suppose this rational has decimal expansion
$$
q=\frac{a}{b}=c.d_1d_2...
$$
Then we have more generally that
$$
10^kq=c_k.d_{k+1}d_{k+2}...
$$
where $10^ka=bc_k+r_k$ and $r_k\in\{0,1,...,b-1\}$ is the remainder after the division $10^ka/b$. Therefore
$$
\frac{r_k}{b}=0.d_{k+1}d_{k+2}...
$$
Now since $r_k$ can only assume finitely many values (this is essentially the apllying pigeonhole principle) the remainder and thus the decimal expansion will eventually repeat itself so that $r_k=r_m$ for some $k<m$. Thus
$$
0.d_{k+1}d_{k+2}...=0.d_{m+1}d_{m+2}...
$$
showing that the decimal expansion is periodic with period $m-k$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just wanted the answer here it is: [Proof that every repeating decimal is rational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198810/proof-that-every-repeating-decimal-is-rational/847020#847020) I had to figure it out to answer a Project Euler problem, the principle is the same as the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b\in\mathbb N$, and assume we want to prove that the decimal expansion of $b/a$ is eventually periodic. If $a>b$, then there exist unique $q,r\in\mathbb Z$ such that $a=qb+r$ with $0\leq r<b$. so $a/b=q+r/b$. Hence, if we can show that $r/b$ is eventually periodic, we are done. So WLOG assume that $a<b$.

One can prove that we can construct a decimal expansion of $a/b$ satisfying the following properties:

> Define a sequence $(r_n)$ recursively, by setting $r_0=$ and
> $$
> r_n=10 r_{n-1}-d_{n-1}\cdot b
> $$
> such that $0\leq r_{n-1}<b$ (note that $r_n$ is uniquely determined by the division-with-remainder theorem). Then a decimal expansion of $a/b$ is given by $=\sum_{i\leq -1} d_i 10^i$.

See e.g. §16 in Elementary Analysis by Kenneth Ross.

Using this, and Theorem 16.3 in Ross (which says that each real number has either a unique decimal expansion or two decimal expansions, one ending in a sequence of all $0$'s and the other ending in a sequence of al $9$'s), one can indeed invoke the pigeon principle:

Each $r_{n-1}$ determines $r_n$ uniquely, and there can at most $b+1$ distinct $r_n$. So there exist integers $m$ and $p$ such that $0\leq m<m+p\leq b$ and $r_m=r_{m+p}$. One can then prove inductively that for $k\geq m+1$, $r_k=r_{k+p}$. For the details I refer to Theorem 16.5 in Ross.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque My apologies, I wasn't aware that this question was a dupe. I don't think my answer is a dupe, as the answers I saw weren't clear to me, so when I found a formal proof in Ross, I thought it might be helpful for someone else in the future too. Can I transfer this answer to the other question, or do you still consider my answer a dupe? In which case I'll delete it.

Comment: It is ok to leave it here.