# Pigeonhole Principle For Rationals: Is This on Rings?

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

I am trying to show using the pigeonhole principle that the decimal
expansion of a rational must become repeating. I started out
by trying to construct the decimal expansion of $\frac{a}{b}$ where
$a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b \neq 0.$ I then was suggested this algorithm
to construct this expansion: \

Let $e_0 = a$, and for all $k \geq 1,$ Let
$$10 \times e_{k-1} = ba_k + r_k$$,
where $0 \leq r_k < b$ (thus is a remainder from the division of $b$) and
$a_k$ is the $k$th digit of the decimal expansion of $\frac{a}{b}$ I can kind of
see how this recursive construction relates to how long division works, but
It is not clear to me how to apply Pigeonhole Principle from then.
I may want to use some form of modulus in this problem, But for whether it
deals with the equivalence classes surrounding $a_k$ or $r_k$, I am not
completely sure. My friend also suggested that there may be a ring-theoretic
way of going about this problem that is simpler and easier to construct. Any
suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is $e_k$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198810/proof-that-every-repeating-decimal-is-rational/847020#847020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pigeonhole principle tells you that eventually you will have two $r_k$s that are the same.  This will happen after $b-1$ divisions at the latest, because you can't have one of the $r$'s be zero or the decimal would terminate.  Now argue that the set of decimals between these two matching ones will repeat because you are doing all the same divisions.