# How to know without factoring whether a division will result in recurring decimals

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions, rational-numbers, number-systems

Assumption: When dividing an integer `n` by another integer `m`, and representing the result as a decimal in base `b`, it will have recurring decimals iif `m` has at least a prime factor that's not in `n`, and it's not common with `b`.

Examples:

- `6 / 100` when represented in base 10 it does not (0.03), because `100 = 2*2*5*5`, in which all factors are common with the ones of base 10 (2 and 5).
- `100 / 6` in base 10 does have recurring decimals (16.6666....), because `6 = 2*3`, which has 3 that's not common with the ones of base 10
- `300 / 6` in base 10 on the other hand doesn't have recurring decimals (50), because the `3` factor gets cleared out as it's common with the numerator.

These also apply when representing the number in any other base.

However, I need to figure this out working with numbers that are big, and that are not integers, but rational numbers, which I have represented as decimals.

So to use this method, I'd have to first transform each number to the rational representation `a / b` by using the continued fraction method (which is already a long algorithm), then factor each number (which will probably be too big to do efficiently), then compare the factors using the method above to get the binary answer.

So I would like to know if there's any way to tell whether the result will have recurring decimals without having to factorise the original ones. As possible not-so-big example inputs (all in base 10 to make thinking easier):

- `3.94625 / 3` does result in recurring decimals: `1.3154166666...`
- `3.5623086 / 3`: doesn't result in recurring decimals: `1.1874362`

Comment: $300/6$ *does* have a recurring decimal of .0000...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting that a fraction is a repeating decimal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197478/detecting-that-a-fraction-is-a-repeating-decimal)

Comment: In my opinion, the first step must be to express the quotient in terms of $$\frac{p}{q},$$ where $p$ and $q$ are each integers.  So, $$\frac{3.94625}{3}$$ becomes $$\frac{394625}{(10)^5 \times 3}.$$  Then, since you are working in base $10$, and since $3$ is not a prime factor of $10$, you know immediately that the fraction will have have an infinite repeating decimal if and only $3$ does not divide $(394625)$.

Comment: @ClydeKertzer Well - The question you linked confirms the assumption I made at the top, but doesn't answer my question

Comment: @user2661923 I'm asking specifically to avoid factoring numbers, because that requires finding `p` + `q`, and then factoring the both of them.

Applying the same method to the other example becomes more apparent of this problem:

`3.5623086 / 3 = 35623086 / (10^7 x 3)`, yet it doesn't have recurring decimals because `3` is a factor of `35623086 = 2 × 3 × 47 × 126323`.

So you have to factorise both `p` and `q`. My question is - is there any way around this?

Comment: Wait, I see - it does get close. `10^n` can always be ignored. Only `q` needs to be factorised, and ignoring every prime present in the base (in this case 10), we only need to check whether `q` divides `p`, which can be done through Euclidean algorithm. So `p` doesn't need to be factorised, but `q` does.

Comment: By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61947/242) in the dupe (case $c =0$) the fraction $r$ terminates in radix $b\iff $ its lowest terms denominator $d$ divides some power of $b$, i.e. $\,b^n r\in\Bbb Z,\,$ for some $n,\,$ i.e. $r$ can be written with denominator $\,b^n.\,$ This can be tested using only fast gcds (no slow factoring) by repeatedly cancelling $\,\gcd(d,b)\,$ from $d$ till they are coprime. If the final value of $d = 1$ then $\,d\mid b^n\,$ for some $n$ so it is terminating; else it is repeating.

Comment: @BillDubuque thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for - Clear explanation on how that applies here